# How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments

Tags: macros

I have a mathematical transformation that takes 16 parameters (grouped into 3+8+5) and would like to make a latex command for it, so that I can easily change the notation for it if the need arises.

As far as I know, both `\def` and `\newcommand` take a maximum of 9 arguments, is there any (recommended) way to extend this?

Comment: Perhaps you might show us the detail of what is wanted. This sounds like a question where the best answer will be to think carefully about the input you really require.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear the parameters are not programmatic, but rather, an unavoidable part of the the maths that I'm using.

Comment: I wonder if there's a magic solution involving [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You are going to have to parse the arguments some at a time and store them into temporary registers or macros. For example

```
\newcommand\foo[9]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \def\tempb{#2}%
    \def\tempc{#3}%
    \def\tempd{#4}%
    \def\tempe{#5}%
    \def\tempf{#6}%
    \def\tempg{#7}%
    \def\temph{#8}%
    \def\tempi{#9}%
    \foocontinued
}
\newcommand\foocontinued[7]{%
    % Do whatever you want with your 9+7 arguments here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks TH - that's the same solution as supplied in the "black TeX magic" link provided by mindcorrosive. I think that I'll use the xargs package, since it will make my code clearer and I like the simple default arguments.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to declare and access/use the variables?

Comment: I ask the same question as @FireFly3000 . I did as you said above and called the two functions as follows:   \pointscolors{100}{red};
            \myarc{0}{0}{0}{0}{3}{2.645751311064591}{0}{-3}{2.645751311064591};   (sorry, I do not know how to format this), with 2 arguments and the next with 9 arguments.   then I get this error:      Argument of \myarc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.90 ...myarc{0}{0}{0}{0}{3}{2.645751311064591}{0}
                                                  {-3}{2.645751311064591};
?

Comment: I removed the "\foocontinued"  from the first block (named "\foo") and my error disappeared.  I think that line is in error because is called without parameters.

Comment: Within the definition-text of `\foocontinued`  you can use the macros `\tempa`..`\tempi` and the arguments `#1`..`#7`, so within the definition-text of `\foocontinued` the first nine arguments  are addressable via macro-calls and the following seven nine arguments are addressable via `#<digit>`-syntax.

Comment: Defining macros `\tempa`...`\tempi` from the first nine arguments implies the need of expanding these macros. During expansion two consecutive hashes from a macro's definition text will collapse into one hash. In order to avoid/compensate this you can use `\edef\tempa{\unexpanded{#1}}%`  instead of `\def\tempa{#1}%`, etc.

Comment: I came here because I want a command to create 4x4 arrays.  Using this answer I created a command `\arrfour` that takes 8 arguments, sets up the array, creates the first two rows (using the 8 arguments) and then calls `\arrfourparttwo` without arguments.  That command is also defined to take 8 arguments, which it uses to create the last two rows and finish the array.  In my document, I call `\arrfour{}` with 16 arguments (16 x `{}`), which seem to be automagically divided between the two commands...

Answer (score 36):

There's the `xargs` [package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xargs), and there's also some [black TeX magic](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-moren9). As for myself, being conditioned in Python, I prefer the key-value parameter syntax provided by `keyval`/`xkeyval` packages.

On an unrelated note, if I find myself needing more than 9 parameters, that usually means that my macro/def/code organization is not very good, and I'd try to improve that first. But of course, there are legitimate situations where 9 parameters are perfectly okay --- especially if you try to build a definition with a lot of knobs and tweaks.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how my googling did not turn up the first option you gave. 
 
The 16 parameters define a nonlinear transformation - they're not options in the macro.

Comment: Actually, xargs does not allow more than 9 arguments - it only gives a neat interface for optional arguments. I'll have to use the TeX hack.

Comment: That's correct. Until you clarified what you need so much parameters for, I assumed it's for a macro, and you'd use the keyval interface. But of course in that case it's better with plain TeX.

Comment: Actually you made me reconsider if I needed all those arguments and I ended up with 6 arguments in stead of 10 :)

Answer (score 27):

**NEW ANSWER**

The `listofitems` package used here is preferable to my original answers below, because `\readlist` does not expand the argument when capturing it, nor does it rely on inconvenient roman-numeral syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\setsepchar{ }
\readlist\arg{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 FinalArgument}
There are \arglen{} arguments.  The thirteenth is \arg[13]
\end{document}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

In a response to [How to use variables inside a command when generating a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99267/how-to-use-variables-inside-a-command-when-generating-a-table)
I mention how the stringstrings package has a \getargs command that will parse large numbers of arguments that are passed within a single { }.  To recap that reply,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\getargs{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 FinalArgument}
There are \narg~arguments.  The thirteenth is \argxiii
\end{document}
```

The result to this example is:

There are 13 arguments. The thirteenth is FinalArgument

---

EDIT: A much more efficient version of `\getargs` is available in the `readarray` package and called `\getargsC` (in deference to David Carlisle's help).  Thus, the same task can be accomplished more quickly with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{document}
\getargsC{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 FinalArgument}
There are \narg~arguments.  The thirteenth is \argxiii
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to show how these techniques can be used to define a command taking several arguments?

Comment: @Psychonaut when you say several arguments, do you mean several arguments within a single set of braces?  For example, the `listofitems` answer at the end of this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348366/why-do-i-get-you-cant-use-a-prefix-with-the-character-0-when-using-ifnu/348378#348378

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the `stringstrings` package has some unwanted side effects due to definitions of `\t` et al, that are commonly used by latex users as shortcuts. BTW, the `readarray` package doesn't do that and seems a better alternative.

Answer (score 12):

Since it's a different technique, I also present the following: local macro definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\NineteenArgs#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
    \def\ArgsTenAndFurther##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9{%
        \def\ArgNineteen####1{%
            ####1##9##8##7##6##5##4##3##2##1#9#8#7#6#5#4#3#2#1%
        }%
        \ArgNineteen%
    }%
    \ArgsTenAndFurther%
}

\begin{document}
                 %1234567890123456789
    \NineteenArgs abcdefghijklmnopqrs
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is beautiful, in a horrifying sort of way. I wanted `\matr 1110 1110 1110 0000`, and `\newcommand{\matr}[9]{\def\matrMore##1##2##3##4##5##6##7{\begin{bmatrix}#1&#2&#3&#4\\#5&#6&#7&#8\\#9&##1&##2&##3\\##4&##5&##6&##7\end{bmatrix}}\matrMore}` did the trick perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped. I trust you like the transparency of the argument naming scheme:-)

Answer (score 8):

First, we define the command `\foo`. It contains a nested command definition for parameters extension. Note it is declared using `\neworrenewcommand`, which defines a command if not defined, or redefine it if it is already defined.*

Parameters with one dash are bound to the first command, while parameters with two dashes are bound to the second command. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Provide a way to declare and renew a command in one command
\newcommand{\neworrenewcommand}[1]{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}

\newcommand{\foo}[9]{
    \neworrenewcommand{\ffoo}[1]{
        #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9 ##1
    }
    \ffoo
}

\begin{document}
    \foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}

    \foo{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}
\end{document}
```

Preview of the result:

[image: preview]

*This is necessary, since the calling `\foo` multiple times redefines the nested command. The `\neworrenewcommand` trick is further explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228865/108649).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is more or less the same as the answer up above: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165324/134574 (using `\newcommand` instead of `\def`).

Comment: Hey! Thank you! Yes, I was wondering if that was possible with `\newcommand` as well and it was. I felt in the mood for documenting it here. :)

Comment: This gives an error if one wants to use the command consecutively, e.g two times.

Error message: Command \*** already defined.

For a working solution look at diligar's answer from above and at Ulrich Diez's comment on it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418343/76400

Comment: @PhilippH This is because the subcommand (`ffoo`) is renewed when called multiple times. I changed its definition using `providecommand`, so it works with multiple invocations.

Comment: @Teepeemm `\providecommand` defines a new command if it isn't already defined. Therefore, the first time the nested command is created and subsequent calls will not redefine it.

Comment: @Teepeemm I understand your point now and you are right! I edited my answer one more time to define the nested command the first time and redefine it for subsequent calls. Thanks for your careful review!

Comment: In order to identify a source of problems when it comes to defining temporary macros from arbitrary arguments, try `\foo{\string#}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}`

Answer (score 6):

This assumes no argument of a weird command contains a weird command. Here for “weird command” I mean one defined with the proposed `\NewWeirdCommand` below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewWeirdCommand}{mmm}
 {% #1 = command to define, #2 = number of arguments, #3 = replacement text
  \cs_new:Npn #1
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__simon_parse_args_tl { #3 }
    \__simon_parse_args:n { #2 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Arg}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \l__simon_parse_args_seq { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__simon_parse_args_tl
\seq_new:N \l__simon_parse_args_seq
\int_new:N \l__simon_parse_args_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simon_parse_args:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__simon_parse_args_seq
  \int_zero:N \l__simon_parse_args_int
  \__simon_parse_arg:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simon_parse_arg:n
 {
  \int_incr:N \l__simon_parse_args_int
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__simon_parse_args_int } > { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__simon_parse_args_tl
   }
   {
    \__simon_parse_arg_aux:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simon_parse_arg_aux:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__simon_parse_args_seq { #2 }
  \__simon_parse_arg:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewWeirdCommand{\foo}{4}{\Arg{1}-\Arg{2}-\Arg{3}-\Arg{4}END}
\NewWeirdCommand{\baz}{16}{%
  \Arg{16}-%
  \Arg{15}-%
  \Arg{14}-%
  \Arg{13}-%
  \Arg{12}-%
  \Arg{11}-%
  \Arg{10}-%
  \Arg{9}-%
  \Arg{8}-%
  \Arg{7}-%
  \Arg{6}-%
  \Arg{5}-%
  \Arg{4}-%
  \Arg{3}-%
  \Arg{2}-%
  \Arg{1}-%
  END%
}

\foo{a}{b}{c}{d}XXXX

\baz{a1}{b1}{c1}{d1}{a2}{b2}{c2}{d2}{a3}{b3}{c3}{d3}{a4}{b4}{c4}{d4}XXXX

\end{document}
```

In the replacement text, `\Arg{<number>}` denotes the corresponding collected argument.

No check is done, so if you define a weird command to have 15 arguments, `\Arg{16}` in the replacement text will output nothing.

[image]

If you are willing to use a slightly different syntax, with all arguments in an additional pair of braces, it's simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewWeirdCommand}{mm}
 {% #1 = command to define, #2 = replacement text
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__simon_args_tl { ##1 }
    #2
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Arg}{m}
 {
  \tl_item:Nn \l__simon_args_tl { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__simon_parse_args_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewWeirdCommand{\foo}{\Arg{1}-\Arg{2}-\Arg{3}-\Arg{4}END}
\NewWeirdCommand{\baz}{%
  \Arg{16}-%
  \Arg{15}-%
  \Arg{14}-%
  \Arg{13}-%
  \Arg{12}-%
  \Arg{11}-%
  \Arg{10}-%
  \Arg{9}-%
  \Arg{8}-%
  \Arg{7}-%
  \Arg{6}-%
  \Arg{5}-%
  \Arg{4}-%
  \Arg{3}-%
  \Arg{2}-%
  \Arg{1}-%
  END%
}

\foo{{a}{b}{c}{d}}XXXX

\baz{{a1}{b1}{c1}{d1}{a2}{b2}{c2}{d2}{a3}{b3}{c3}{d3}{a4}{b4}{c4}{d4}}XXXX

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hehe, the `weird` command. I like it. `:P`

Answer (score 4):

I show something similar as ergreg's solution, but without usage of any special macro language. Only pure TeX language is used.

```
\newcount\argnum
\def\argsdef#1#2{\def#1{\argnum=1\def\useargs{#2}\inargs}}
\def\inargs{\futurelet\next\inargsA}
\def\inargsA{\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter\inargsB \else \expandafter\useargs \fi}
\def\inargsB#1{\expandafter\def\csname Arg:\the\argnum\endcsname{#1}%
   \advance\argnum by1 
   \inargs}
\def\arg#1{\csname Arg:#1\endcsname}

\argsdef\a{\arg{1}:\arg{3}:\arg{5}::\arg{11}:\arg{13}}
\argsdef\b{\arg{6}-\arg{5}-\arg{4}-\arg{3}-\arg{2}-\arg{1}}

\a{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}{M}

\b{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can offer a macro `\KeepKthOfLArguments` which picks the K-th undelimited argument of a list of L undelimited arguments.

When doing macro-programming, you can implement a "mechanism" where the L arguments are gathered  and accumulated within a single macro argument which in turn holds the list of L arguments and which in turn is passed to an internal macro which in turn does things in terms of `\KeepKthOfLArguments`.

I don't recommend using this for macros at user-level.

At user-level I recommend interfaces that do list-processing, e.g., with keyval-syntax. (keyval-syntax implies processing a comma-separated list of key=value-pairs.)

Things like `\pgfplotstableread` of the package **pgfplots** and the facilities of the package **datatool** for iterating on databases and comma-lists and property-lists of **expl3** might be of interest as well.

But sometimes I use such things with macros that both generate and process large lists of undelimited arguments automatically without the need of the user passing/typing these arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% Code for \KeepKthOfLArguments: 
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Keep only the K-th of L consecutive undelimited arguments.
%%   ( IF K < 1 OR K > L just remove L consecutive undelimited arguments. )
%%=============================================================================
%% \KeepKthOfLArguments{<integer number K>}%
%%                     {<integer number L>}%
%%                     <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments>
%%
%% If L < 1 yields nothing.
%% Else:
%%   If K >= 1 and K < L  yields:
%%     <K-th undelimited argument from <sequence of L consecutive undelimited 
%%      arguments>>
%%   If K < 1 or K > L
%%     (-> there is no K-th argument in the
%%         <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments> )
%%   yields nothing  but removal of <sequence of L consecutive 
%%          undelimited arguments>
\newcommand\KeepKthOfLArguments[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <integer number L>
  \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#2 000}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork[2]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>
  % #2: <L letters m >
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K is smaller than one:
    \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{\UD@stopromannumeral}{}%
  }{% K is not smaller than one:
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
    }{%
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop{#1}{#2}%
    }{#2}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop[4]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>  
  % #2: <L letters m>
  % (For detecting whether K>L or K<=L, during the loop letters m will
  %  be removed both from #1 and #2 until at least one of these arguments 
  %  is empty.
  %  When the loop terminates with 0<K<=L, #1 will be empty and #2
  %  will hold an amount of letters m corresponding to the the 
  %  difference L-K.
  %  When the loop terminates with K>L, #1 will not be empty and #2
  %  will be empty.
  % )
  % #3: <K-1 letters m>
  % #4: <L letters m>
  % (#3 and #4 will be left untouched during the loop so they can be 
  %  used for performing appropriate action when loop terminates as
  %  it is known whether K>L.)
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% We have K<=L:
     \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{%
       #3%
      }{%
       \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{\UD@stopromannumeral}%
      }{}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{% We have K>L:
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#4}{\UD@stopromannumeral}{}%
    }{% We don't know yet whether K<=L or K>L, thus remove letters m and 
      % do another iteration:
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#2%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop
        \expandafter{%
          \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
        }%
      }{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{<N letters m>}%
%%                                        {<argument 1>}%
%%                                        {<argument 2>}%
%%                                        <sequence of consecutive 
%%                                         undelimited arguments>
%%.............................................................................
%% Removes the first N undelimited arguments from the <sequence of 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments>, then inserts  
%% <argument 1><argument 2>
%%
%% On the one hand when providing <argument 2> empty, you can use 
%% <argument 1> for nesting calls to \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments.
%% On the other hand you can provide a <space token> for stopping
%% \romannumeral-expansion as  <argument 1> and have the
%% macro grab the <K-th undelimited argument> from the <sequence of L 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments> as <argument 2>.
%%
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments[3]{%
  %% #1: <N letters m>  
  %% #2: <Argument 1>   
  %% #3: <Argument 2>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{#2#3}{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{%
      \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
      }{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% End of code for \KeepKthOfLArguments.
\makeatother

\newcommand\MacroWithThirtyNestedParameters[1]{%
  This is paramter 1: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{1}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 2: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{2}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 3: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{3}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 4: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{4}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 5: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{5}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 6: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{6}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 7: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{7}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 8: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{8}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 9: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{9}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 10: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{10}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 11: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{11}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 12: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{12}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 13: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{13}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 14: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{14}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 15: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{15}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 16: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{16}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 17: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{17}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 18: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{18}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 19: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{19}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 20: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{20}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 21: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{21}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 22: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{22}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 23: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{23}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 24: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{24}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 25: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{25}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 26: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{26}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 27: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{27}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 28: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{28}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 29: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{29}{30}#1}\\
  This is paramter 30: \textbf{\KeepKthOfLArguments{30}{30}#1}%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
\MacroWithThirtyNestedParameters{%
  {Word 1}%
  {Word 2}%
  {Word 3}%
  {Word 4}%
  {Word 5}%
  {Word 6}%
  {Word 7}%
  {Word 8}%
  {Word 9}%
  {Word 10}%
  {Word 11}%
  {Word 12}%
  {Word 13}%
  {Word 14}%
  {Word 15}%
  {Word 16}%
  {Word 17}%
  {Word 18}%
  {Word 19}%
  {Word 20}%
  {Word 21}%
  {Word 22}%
  {Word 23}%
  {Word 24}%
  {Word 25}%
  {Word 26}%
  {Word 27}%
  {Word 28}%
  {Word 29}%
  {Word 30}%
}%

\vfill

\noindent\verb|\KeepKthOfLArguments| does deliver the result after two
expansion-steps:

\begin{verbatim}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{3}{11}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}%
}%
\end{verbatim}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \KeepKthOfLArguments{3}{11}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}%
}%

\noindent\texttt{\string\test: \meaning\test}%

\vfill\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you don't like to specify the amount of undelimited arguments but only which one to pick, if present, I can offer a macro `\ExtractKthArg`.

When doing macro-programming, you can pass an arbitrary sequence of undelimited arguments via nesting that sequence into a single undelimited macro argument and apply `\ExtractKthArg` on that single argument for extracting a specific element from the sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
\makeatother

\newcommand\MacroWithThirtyNestedParameters[1]{%
  This is paramter 1: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{1}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 2: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{2}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 3: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 4: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 5: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{5}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 6: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 7: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{7}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 8: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{8}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 9: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{9}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 10: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{10}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 11: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{11}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 12: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{12}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 13: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{13}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 14: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{14}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 15: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{15}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 16: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{16}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 17: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{17}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 18: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{18}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 19: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{19}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 20: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{20}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 21: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{21}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 22: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{22}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 23: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{23}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 24: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{24}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 25: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{25}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 26: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{26}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 27: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{27}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 28: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{28}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 29: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{29}{not available}{#1}}\\
  This is paramter 30: \textbf{\ExtractKthArg{30}{not available}{#1}}%
}%

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-1in}\enlargethispage{1in}

\noindent\verb|\ExtractKthArg{-1}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{-1}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{1}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{1}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{2}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{2}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{5}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{5}{not available}{ABCDE}\\
\verb|\ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{ABCDE}|: \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{ABCDE}

\vfill

\noindent
\MacroWithThirtyNestedParameters{%
  {Word 1}%
  {Word 2}%
  {Word 3}%
  {Word 4}%
  {Word 5}%
  {Word 6}%
  {Word 7}%
  {Word 8}%
  {Word 9}%
  {Word 10}%
  {Word 11}%
  {Word 12}%
  {Word 13}%
  {Word 14}%
  {Word 15}%
  {Word 16}%
  {Word 17}%
  {Word 18}%
  {Word 19}%
  {Word 20}%
  {Word 21}%
  {Word 22}%
  {Word 23}%
  {Word 24}%
  {Word 25}%
  {Word 26}%
  {Word 27}%
  {Word 28}%
  {Word 29}%
  {Word 30}%
}%

\vfill

\noindent\verb|\ExtractKthArg| does deliver the result after two
expansion-steps:

\begin{verbatim}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}}%
}%
\end{verbatim}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}}%
}%

\noindent\texttt{\string\test: \meaning\test}%

\vfill\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With both examples everything works by means of expansion only. No temporary macros get defined from arguments. This implies that the arguments themselves can contain hashes. E.g., things like `#1` don't yield error-messages as would be the case when "naively" defining temporary macros in terms of `\def` from such arguments. This also implies that arguments can contain consecutive hashes, e.g., `##`, without them being reduced to a single hash `#` as would be the case at the time of expanding temporary macros defined from such arguments.

---

I recommend to use such things at best when list-processing-interfaces, e.g. key=value-interfaces, and processing of databases/data tables by means of pgfplots or datatool are not possible, and when furthermore the use of the many arguments is so interwoven that it is not possible to split the thing into several macros each of which grabs/processes only a subset of the arguments consisting of less than 10 arguments.
In practice, I have never encountered the latter not being possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error as @Herman-Jaramillo, so here is my correction of @TH's answer:

```
\newcommand\foo[9]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \def\tempb{#2}%
    \def\tempc{#3}%
    \def\tempd{#4}%
    \def\tempe{#5}%
    \def\tempf{#6}%
    \def\tempg{#7}%
    \def\temph{#8}%
    \foocontinued#9
}
\newcommand\foocontinued[7]{%
    % Do whatever you want with your 8+7 arguments here.
}
```

Then later:

```
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}}
```

**Notice that 9 through 15 are themselves in brackets.** This solution is not perfect, since you cannot use 15 sets of brackets next to each other as cleanly as one might desire, but it worked for me.

Comment: Defining macros `\tempa`...`\temph` from the first eight arguments implies the need of expanding these macros. During expansion two consecutive hashes from a macro's definition text will collapse into one hash. In order to avoid/compensate this you can use `\edef\tempa{\unexpanded{#1}}%`  instead of `\def\tempa{#1}%`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Better way should be:

```
\newcommand\foo[9]{%
\def\tempa{#1}%
\def\tempb{#2}%
\def\tempc{#3}%
\def\tempd{#4}%
\def\tempe{#5}%
\def\tempf{#6}%
\def\tempg{#7}%
\def\temph{#8}%
\foocontinued%#9 <- remove it
}

\newcommand\foocontinued[7]{%
% Do whatever you want with your 8+7 arguments here.
}
```

Then later

```
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}
```

e.g. NO doble bracket there.

But this solution is not elegant at all, but working.

Comment: What does this add to an already existing answer?

Comment: Defining macros `\tempa`...`\temph` from the first eight arguments implies the need of expanding these macros. During expansion two consecutive hashes from a macro's definition text will collapse into one hash. In order to avoid/compensate this you can use `\edef\tempa{\unexpanded{#1}}%`  instead of `\def\tempa{#1}%`, etc.