# Explanation of the usage of a particular new command to personalize it

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

A guy had a problem personalizing his ToC, and you helped him suggesting to use this lines:

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
  \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \chapter*{#2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}
```

Could you explain me

1. Why do you write `[2]` next to `\mychapter`?
2. Why do you use the hashtag for numerating?
3. What is the function of `\addcontentline`?

I hope no to bother you too much, I am just a new young user trying to understand the software.

Comment: Hi and welcome, why does an unnumbered chapter get a (fixed) number? Where have you taken this piece of code from?

Answer (score 5):

1. Why do you write "`[2]`" next to `\mychapter`?

   Taken from [`source2e.pdf`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) - the source documentation for LaTeX2e (section **11.3 Command definitions**, p 23):

   > ```
   > \newcommand*{<\FOO>}[<i>]{<TEXT>}
   > ```
   >
   > User command to define `\FOO` to be a macro with `i` arguments (`i` = 0 if missing)
   >   having the definition `<TEXT>`. Produces an error if `\FOO` already defined.
   >   Normally the command is defined to be `\long` (*i.e.* it may take multiple paragraphs
   >   in its argument). In the star-form, the command is not defined as `\long`
   >   and a blank line in any argument to the command would generate an error.

   So, the general use of `\newcommand` (and also for `\renewcommand` and `\providecommand`) is to include the number of arguments within square brackets. Using your definition, `\mychapter` will take two (`2`) arguments.

   Also see [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/5764) (beyond this scope and perhaps more technical, but still relevant, see [What is the difference between `\def` and `\newcommand`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/5764)).
2. Why do you use the hashtag for numerating?

   Taken from [The TeXBook](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (chapter **20 Definitions (also called Macros)**, p 198):

   > As soon as you get the hang of simple macros [...],
   >   you will probably begin to think, "Boy, wouldn't it be nice if I could have a
   >   macro in which some of the text in the expansion is changeable? I'd like to be able
   >   to stick different things into the middle of that text." Well, TeX has good news for
   >   you: Control sequences can be defined in terms of parameters, and you can supply
   >   arguments that will be substituted for the parameters.
   >
   > ... The symbol `#1` stands for the first parameter to the macro, ... There can be as
   >   many as nine parameters, `#1` to `#9`, [...]

   So you would reference the arguments within `\mychapter` using `#1` and/or `#2` since the macro takes two arguments. `#1` represents the first argument and `#2` represents the second argument.

   Relevant, if needed, see [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/5764).
3. What is the function of `\addcontentsline`?

   Taken from [`source2e.pdf`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **61.3 Table of Contents etc.**, p 287-):

   > The `\addcontentsline{<table>}{<type>}{<entry>}` command allows the user to
   >   add his/her own entry to a Table of Contents, etc. The command adds the entry
   >   `\contentsline{<type>}{<entry>}{<page>}` to the `.<table>` file.
   >
   > This macro is implemented as an application of `\addtocontents`.

   So `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}` inserts an entry `\contentsline{chapter}{#2}{<page>}` into the `.toc` file, where `#2` is the second argument of `\mychapter`. The `<page>` entry is determined when the page is actually shipped out, as that's the nature of TeX's asynchronous shipout routine and page references.

   You'll note that different `<type>`s have different formatting in the ToC. Chapters look different from sections, which are (or at least could be) different from subsections, etc. The differences require one to supply a `<type>` with the `\addcontentsline` macro, as is done in `\mychapter`.

Comment: Your answer is so much more erudite than mine... :-)

Answer (score 4):

> why do you write "[2]" next to `\mychapter`

Because the macro is being defined as taking 2 arguments. The arguments are evidently (a) the intended chapter number and (b) the title of the chapter.

> Why do you use the hashtag for numerating

Because that's LaTeX/TeX syntax for referring to the arguments of a macro: `#1` is the first argument, `#2` is the second, etc.

> What is the function of `\addcontentline`

For some reason, the creator of the `\mychapter` macro (I swear, it wasn't me!) chose to use `\chapter*` rather than `\chapter` to typeset the title of the chapter. In the main LaTeX document classes, `\chapter*` (a) creates unnumbered chapters and (b) does *not* automatically create an entry in the Table of Contents. The `\addcontentsline` macro is a manual way of inserting that information to the file that creates the ToC information.

Comment: Congratulations for your deserved membership of the 100K club!

Comment: There's a party in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Comment: @egreg - I'm on my way. :-)