# Double backslash or \cr in \newcommand to be used in a table

Tags: tables, macros

I have a `\newcommand*\mycmd[3]{#1 & #2 & #3 \\}` that is used in a tabular environment later, like this

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\mycmd{a}{b}{c}
\mycmd{d}{e}{f}
\end{tabular}
```

But the double backslash is ignored. I already tried to change the `\\` to the real `\cr`, but it is also ignored, the rowbreak does just not happen.

How do I have to define my command to be able to use `\\` or `\cr` inside it?

Comment: I see nothing strange and the tabular is built as expected.

Comment: You've been on site long enough to know that isn't a useful way to construct a question:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, you are right, should have looken more carefully to the logs. See my comment on the accepted answer what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always post fully compilable examples: This compiles just as expected

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand*\mycmd[3]{#1 & #2 & #3 \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\mycmd{a}{b}{c}
\mycmd{d}{e}{f}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem was not the `\\ ` or `\cr`, but in my real world code I need more than 10 parameters and did not realize that only 9 are allowed... I found solutions there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments

Comment: That is why we always ask you to prepare a full MWE. And that you test that MWE. Safes us all a lot of time