# How to make more-than-9-argument-commands work with tabular?

Tags: tables, macros, parameters

I have a command that needs more than 9 arguments. I stumbled over this solution: [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments). This works fine in regular text. But I tried using this within a `tabular` environment, but then I get `undefined control sequence` errors. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\foo[9]{%
 \def\tempa{#1}%
 \def\tempb{#2}%
 \def\tempc{#3}%
 \def\tempd{#4}%
 \def\tempe{#5}%
 \def\tempf{#6}%
 \def\tempg{#7}%
 \def\temph{#8}%
 \def\tempi{#9}%
 \foocont
}
\newcommand\foocont[1]{\tempa & \tempb & \tempc & \tempd & \tempe & \tempf & \tempg & \temph & \tempi & #1 \cr}

\begin{tabular}{*{10}c}
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you remove all `&`, the `\cr` and the `tabular` environment, and just call `\foo` with 10 arguments the code compiles just fine (printing out `123456789a`).

How can I make this "argument extension" work together with `tabular`?

Comment: `\gdef` or `\xdef` but I doubt this is a very good way

Comment: why not have a more usual, and more easily extendible,  syntax such as `\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first table cell, where `\foo` is executed, is also a local group. After the next `&` the local meanings of `\tempb`, `\tempc`, ... are lost.

There are several ways

### Global definitions

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\foo[9]{%
 \gdef\tempa{#1}%
 \gdef\tempb{#2}%
 \gdef\tempc{#3}%
 \gdef\tempd{#4}%
 \gdef\tempe{#5}%
 \gdef\tempf{#6}%
 \gdef\tempg{#7}%
 \gdef\temph{#8}%
 \gdef\tempi{#9}%
 \foocont
}
\newcommand\foocont[1]{\tempa & \tempb & \tempc & \tempd & \tempe & \tempf &
\tempg & \temph & \tempi & #1 \cr}

\begin{tabular}{*{10}c}
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Expansion

The following example expands the `\temp...` macros via `\protected@edef`. This supports LaTeX protection mechanism via `\protect` and robust commands. The `\temp...` macros can even be assigned locally only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\foo[9]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \def\tempb{#2}%
  \def\tempc{#3}%
  \def\tempd{#4}%
  \def\tempe{#5}%
  \def\tempf{#6}%
  \def\tempg{#7}%
  \def\temph{#8}%
  \def\tempi{#9}%
  \foocont
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\foocont[1]{%
  \protected@edef\process@me{%
    \endgroup
    \tempa & \tempb & \tempc & \tempd & \tempe & \tempf &
    \tempg & \temph & \tempi & #1 \cr
  }%
  \process@me
}
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{*{10}c}
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### One level expansion

The use of `\protect` for fragile commands can be avoided, if the
`\temp...` macros are only expanded once. The command `\unexpanded` of e-TeX helps. An alternative without e-TeX uses token register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\foo[9]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \def\tempb{#2}%
  \def\tempc{#3}%
  \def\tempd{#4}%
  \def\tempe{#5}%
  \def\tempf{#6}%
  \def\tempg{#7}%
  \def\temph{#8}%
  \def\tempi{#9}%
  \foocont
}
\newcommand*\foocont[1]{%
  \edef\processme{%
    \endgroup
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempa} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempb} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempc} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempd} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempe} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempf} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempg} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\temph} &
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempi} & #1 \cr
  }%
  \processme
}

\begin{tabular}{*{10}c}
\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As David suggests in the comments, another approach is use a comma separated syntax:

```
\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a}
```

You can then loop over the entries and put them into place. There are still some expansion issues because we are working inside a table but you can get around these using the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to build each row as you loop over the arguments using `\foreach` from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

The main advantage of doing it this way is that the code easily expands to an arbitrary number of arguments. Secondly, the code is shorter and easier to maintain because you do not need to treat each argument specially, as Heiko had to do. If you really want you can check that the number of arguments is correct, but this seems like overkill to me as too few rows will be clear from the output and too many will automatically give an error.

I changed the MWE to convince myself that this is working to get:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \global\def\sep{}% will expand to & except for the first column
  \global\let\myrow\relax% will become the row built from #1
  \foreach \arg in {#1} {% loop over #1 to build \myrow
     \xappto\myrow{\sep\arg}% global expansion
     \gdef\sep{&}% make the next separator &
  }%
  \myrow\\% print the row
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c|}}
  \foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a}
  \foo{111,22,,444,55,{10,000},77,88,99,a}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(Btw, as is explained in the documentation of the [booktabs package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), using vertical lines to separate the columns is generally a bad idea. I have done it above only to show that the code is working.)