# conTeXt Mkiv: the number of parameters can not be more than 9?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

For testing, I have a definition:

```
\define[9]\DEFINETEST{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9}
```

`context test` can work fine, when I modify the above into:

```
\define[10]\DEFINETEST{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8,#9,#10}
```

I got a error:

```
test.tex: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \DEFINETEST
```

What's wrong with that? Thanks!

Comment: Since ConTeXt is based on TeX, the maximum number of 9 parameters is  inherited. There are ways to circumvert this, though (at least on (La)TeX, so I guess the same applies to ConTeXt). The question is do you *really* need 10 parameters?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, Thank you for reminding! Yes I hope to use more than 10 parameters, there is a resolution?

Comment: See here: [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2134/3954). But a key-value approach seems to be more appropriate than having more than 10 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use a key-value interface.

```
\startluacode
userdata = userdata or { }

function userdata.define_test(args, idx) 
    args = utilities.parsers.settings_to_array(args)
    context(args[idx])
end
\stopluacode

\unprotect
\define\definetest{\dosingleempty\do_define_test}

\def\do_define_test[#1]{%
  \iffirstargument
    \def\getarg##1{\ctxlua{userdata.define_test([==[#1]==],##1)}}%
    \getarg{1}
    \getarg{5}
    \getarg{11}
  \fi
}
\protect

\starttext
\definetest[one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve]
\stoptext
```

[image]