# How do I install and--or use opmac using texlive?

Tags: compiling, plain-tex, opmac, csplain

I wanted to give [*opmac*](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html) a try. It is supposed to be part of [*csplain*](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csplain?lang=en), which is supposed to be part of texlive.

I am running `TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015)` using debian from ubuntu 14.04.

But when I try to compile a plain tex document using `\input opmac` I get the following errors:

```
tex opmactest.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=tex)
(./opmactest.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex
(./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex         (./opmac.tex
(./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex (./opmac.tex
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
l.3 \input opmac.tex

No pages of output.
```

MWE:

```
\input opmac

\typosize[11/13] % setting the basic font size and the baselineskip
\margins/1 a4 (1,1,1,1)in % setting 1in margins for A4 paper


Help me get my feet back on the ground

\bye
```

Comment: Not sure how I really installed. Any way to check?

Comment: I think this is how I installed my copy: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html  If I had installed the ubuntu package I would be 2 years behind I think, I would not have texlive 2015.

Comment: Sorry. Yes. You installed from upstream. Is your installation current? This is part of TeX Live and your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: This is the odd thing, I have absolutely never had any problems finding any package, until now.  I do not know if it is current, I guess I could update it, but really it is not more than a year or so at this point.

Comment: `kpsewhich opmac.tex
./opmac.tex`

Comment: Wait! Why do you have `opmac.tex` in your working directory? I should have noticed this before.

Comment: @cfr turning red here...  I kind of used the wrong file name, then didn't delete it, and of course I guess the system used that instead of the right file.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, it took me long enough, too!

Comment: Well, I guess you "helped me get my feet back on the ground" :)

Comment: @AFeldman  Be careful: it's difficult to happily use LaTeX again after trying OPmac :)

Comment: @User I had hoped that I could happily use both, kind of the way that I can apply plain tex within latex.  But I guess I'm early on my journey to wherever I'm going with this... Thanks for the warning.  Nice to finally meet _the_ User.

Comment: @AFeldman  I only meant that OPmac is so nice that you wouldn't come back using LaTeX again, and not that it's difficult to use both at the same time.  Hey, you've already met me!  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305383/how-to-write-macro-with-variable-amount-of-text-variables/305433?noredirect=1#comment742357_305433

Comment: @User you're _that_ person.  Thanks for pitching in on that question, and for being so kind as to try to explain it to me.  Honestly, I have been getting a bit tired of the "wordiness' of how things are done using latex, at least compared to plain. Now, if I started to use plain+opmac, in Star Wars terms, would that be coming into the light, or the darkness?

Comment: @AFeldman  You're welcome.  Sorry I don't know Star Wars, but I'd say light.  Remember,  "simplicity is power".

Comment: @AFeldman If you don't like the wordiness of LaTeX, don't try LaTeX 3 syntax ...

Comment: @cfr you know I noticed that too.

Comment: @User I just got around to fooling around with Opmac.  And it made me really annoyed at how many braces I type with LaTeX and also how annoying it is to simply change a font within a document.  Now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based the console output from your compilation of `opmactest.tex` and our discussion in comments, it seems you forgot to remove an earlier test file which you had called `opmac.tex` from your working directory. This file presumably includes the line

```
\input opmac
```

or

```
\input opmac.tex
```

In either case, the file inputs itself and then inputs itself again and again and again. It would continue indefinitely except that TeX cuts off the nesting. That is, it limits the levels of file nesting allowed, effectively blocking the infinite regress.

Remove the spurious `opmac.tex` from your working directory and `opmactest.tex` should compile fine. It compiles OK for me with TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Comment: you don't need to assume it: the log is telling you that the run is loading a `./opmac.tex` at the current local directory.

Comment: @erreka Yes. But I'm assuming something about its contents.

Comment: I don't think you are "assuming" it either: you *suspect* that the file calls itself.

Comment: Well, at least it only called itself 15 times at a go.  When I look at the log above it screams to me `(preloaded format=tex)
(./dummytest.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex
(./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex         (./dummy.tex
(./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex (./dummy.tex
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=15].
l.3 \input dummy.tex` for leaving that file there after I _realized_ that it would not work with opmac.tex as a filename because it would call itself.