# Why do I get "! You can't use a prefix with `the character 0'." when using \ifnum?

Tags: conditionals, pgfmath

Using a `pgffor` loop, I run through a comma-delimited list to separate the CMYK values. I think the problem is in my `\ifnum` comparison. I am getting an error. Obviously I simplified the code to keep things in focus.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\addcolor[1]{%
  \foreach \item [count=\step] in {#1} {%
    \ifnum\step=1 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{\item}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=2 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueM{\item}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=3 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\item}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=4 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueK{\item}\fi%
    \global\valueC\global\valueM\global\valueY\global\valueK%
  }%
}%
\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
\begin{document}
\section{Current CMYK Values}
C:\valueC M:\valueM Y:\valueY K:\valueK
\end{document}
```

## Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't in the `\ifnum`, but in the use of `\global\valueC`.  The use of `\global` is intended for use with definitions or assignments, to specify the scope of the definition or assignment. So `\global\def...` or `\global\let...` are typical.  Since `\valueC` is not a definition or an assignment, the syntax `\global\valueC` does not mean anything useful.

I am not sure what was intended by `\global\valueC`, but if you mean to make the definition of `\valueC` global, you can use `\global\let\valueC\valueC`. [I also changed `\item` to `\xitem`, because using an already defined command makes me squeamish]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\addcolor[1]{%
  \foreach \xitem [count=\step] in {#1} {%
    \ifnum\step=1 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{\xitem}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=2 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueM{\xitem}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=3 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\xitem}\fi%
    \ifnum\step=4 \pgfmathsetmacro\valueK{\xitem}\fi%
    \global\let\valueC\valueC\global\let\valueM\valueM%
    \global\let\valueY\valueY\global\let\valueK\valueK%
  }%
}%
\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
\begin{document}
\section{Current CMYK Values}
C:\valueC{} M:\valueM{} Y:\valueY{} K:\valueK
\end{document}
```

[image]

Joseph suggests an even more streamlined approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\addcolor[1]{%
  \foreach \xitem [count=\step] in {#1} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\xitem}
    \ifnum\step=1 \global\let\valueC\temp\fi%
    \ifnum\step=2 \global\let\valueM\temp\fi%
    \ifnum\step=3 \global\let\valueY\temp\fi%
    \ifnum\step=4 \global\let\valueK\temp\fi%
  }%
}%
\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
\begin{document}
\section{Current CMYK Values}
C:\valueC{} M:\valueM{} Y:\valueY{} K:\valueK
\end{document}
```

Finally, here is a way with `\listofitems`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,listofitems}
\newcommand\addcolor[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist\cvalues{#1}%
  \readlist\clabels{C,M,Y,K}%
  \readlist\cquence{1,2,3,4}%
  \foreachitem\xitem\in\cquence{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\cvalues[\xitem]}%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname value\clabels[\xitem]\endcsname\temp%
  }%
}%
\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
\begin{document}
\section{Current CMYK Values}
C:\valueC{} M:\valueM{} Y:\valueY{} K:\valueK
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to avoid the save stack issues and have something like `\pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\item}\global\let\valueC=\temp`.

Comment: When mentioning something like `\global\valueC` is a problem in an answer it would be good to either explain why, or provide a link to an explanation.

Comment: @GeoffPointer Thanks.  I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a sledgehammer; anyway, `\global\valueC` is illegal and should be

```
\global\let\valueC\valueC
```

But there's a better way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addcolor[1]{%
  \add@color#1\@nil
}
\def\add@color#1,#2,#3,#4\@nil{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueM{#2}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{#3}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueK{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
C:\valueC \quad M:\valueM \quad Y:\valueY \quad K:\valueK

\addcolor{1,2*3,3+12,4}
C:\valueC \quad M:\valueM \quad Y:\valueY \quad K:\valueK

\end{document}
```

[image]

An even easier way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\addcolor{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \valueC { \fp_eval:n { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } } }
  \tl_set:Nx \valueM { \fp_eval:n { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 } } }
  \tl_set:Nx \valueY { \fp_eval:n { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 3 } } }
  \tl_set:Nx \valueK { \fp_eval:n { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { 4 } } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addcolor{0,20,100,0}
C:\valueC \quad M:\valueM \quad Y:\valueY \quad K:\valueK

\addcolor{1,2*3,3+12,4}
C:\valueC \quad M:\valueM \quad Y:\valueY \quad K:\valueK

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is interesting that you think the LaTeX 3 syntax is easier :) I like sledgehammers. When things just need to work, give them a wack.

Comment: @macmadness86 Isn't it? By the way, `\fp_eval:n` is much more accurate than `\pgfmathparse`.