# Macro with more than 9 arguments

Tags: macros, chess, xskak

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}        % https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{xskak} % https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak

\newcommand*\hestA[2][\svarstedA]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi]{#2}}}
\newcommand*\opgaverLoesningerA[1]{\hestA{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand*\opgaverLoesningerEkstra[6]{%
  \def\tempA{#1}%
  \def\tempB{#2}%
  \def\tempC{#3}%
  \def\tempD{#4}%
  \def\tempE{#5}%
  \def\tempF{#6}%
  \opgaverLoesninger
}
\newcommand*\opgaverLoesninger[6]{%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newgame
    \fenboard{\tempB \tempA - - 0 1}%
    \scalebox{1.2}{\showboard}%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{\tempC}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newgame
    \fenboard{\tempE \tempD - - 0 1}%
    \scalebox{1.2}{\showboard}%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{\tempF}}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newgame
    \fenboard{#2 #1 - - 0 1}%
    \scalebox{1.2}{\showboard}%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{#3}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newgame
    \fenboard{#5 #4 - - 0 1}%
    \scalebox{1.2}{\showboard}%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{#6}}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\opgaverLoesninger%
  {w}{6k1/6p1/1p5p/3r4/1P6/6P1/4B1KP/8}{Lc4}%
  {w}{1k6/pp6/2p3p1/4n1P1/8/P6P/KP1B4/8}{Lf4}%
  {w}{8/1p4kp/p5p1/B7/3n4/1P5P/2P3P1/6K1}{Lc3}%
  {w}{k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8}{Le4}

\end{document}
```

When I compile using `xelatex`, I get the error

```
! Paragraph ended before \FenBoard was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.73   {w}{1k6/pp6/2p3p1/4n1P1/8/P6P/KP1B4/8}{Lf4}
                                                  %
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

P.S. I think it is related to the fact that I try to have more than 9 arguments (here it is 12 arguments) in my macro but I am not sure.

Comment: Your `\opgaverLoesningerEkstra` is never called and o \tempB is undefined at the first \fenboard. Beside this I don't understand what you are trying to do and imho commands with more than 3 or 4 arguments are madness.

Comment: you can not have nore than 9 arguments but you shouldn't ever need more than 2 or 3. use a comma or `\\ `separated list to allow arbitrary arguments `\foo{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}` one argument with a list, not `\foo{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}{k}`

Comment: What I like to do is pass macros as arguments, and each of those can have up to 8 arguments.  Is 64 enough?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/5764)

Comment: @JohnKormylo shouldn't it be 9 times 9 so 81 arguments?

Comment: @Skillmon - Oops, I tend to think in base 8.  (I knew I was a C programmer when I got on an evelator and asked someone to press 0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about having five boards to draw? Or eight?

Here's an implementation that accepts *any* number of boards and outputs them in pairs in `figure` environments. If the number is odd, the last one is output by itself in another `figure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xskak}

\setchessboard{smallboard}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\opgaverLoesninger}{m}
 {
  \svend_opgaver_loesninger:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
\seq_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \svend_opgaver_loesninger:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq
     {
      \__svend_opgaver_board:nn
       { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 1 } } 
       { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 2 } } 
      \__svend_opgaver_caption:n { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 3 } }
     }
   }
  \__svend_opgaver_make_tables:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_board:nn
 {
  \newgame
  \fenboard{#2 ~ #1 ~ - ~ - ~ 0 ~ 1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_caption:n
 {
  \scalebox{1.2}{\showboard}\par
  \vspace*{2ex}
  {\LARGE Løsning: ~ \textcolor{blue}{#1}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_make_tables:
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
  \int_if_odd:nT { \seq_count:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq }
   {
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 2 } { \seq_count:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq }
   {
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \seq_item:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq { ##1 }
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \seq_item:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq { ##1+1 }
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
   }
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
   {
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \tl_use:N \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
    \end{figure}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\opgaverLoesninger{
  w, 6k1/6p1/1p5p/3r4/1P6/6P1/4B1KP/8, Lc4 \\
  w, 1k6/pp6/2p3p1/4n1P1/8/P6P/KP1B4/8, Lf4 \\
  w, 8/1p4kp/p5p1/B7/3n4/1P5P/2P3P1/6K1, Lc3 \\
  w, k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8, Le4 \\
  w, k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8, Le4
}

\end{document}
```

Instead of a syntax with braces, separating boards with `\\` and data in each one with commas is simpler and more readable.

[image]

[image]

With slight changes, you can also set the magnification for the boards (default 1.2) and the number of boards per row (default 2).

The magnification is changed with `mag=<factor>`, the number of boards per row is set with `n=<number>` in the optional argument to `\opgaverLoesninger`.

The option `single` (a boolean, `single=true` is implicit) will make a single figure environment, but you're responsible for it to fit on a page, of course. It is present in the example just by way of example. If you try `\opgaverLoesninger[single]{...}` (same mandatory argument for five boards), the float will be too large (not with four boards).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xskak}

\setchessboard{smallboard}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\opgaverLoesninger}{O{}m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { svend/opgaver } { n=2, mag=1.2, single=false, #1 }
  \svend_opgaver_loesninger:n { #2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { svend/opgaver }
 {
  n      .int_set:N  = \l__svend_opgaver_n_int,
  mag    .tl_set:N   = \l__svend_opgaver_mag_tl,
  single .bool_set:N = \l__svend_opgaver_single_bool,
  single .default:n  = true,
 }

\tl_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_final_tl
\seq_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \svend_opgaver_loesninger:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_in_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq
     {
      \__svend_opgaver_board:nn
       { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 1 } } 
       { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 2 } } 
      \__svend_opgaver_caption:n { \clist_item:nn { ##1 } { 3 } }
     }
   }
  \__svend_opgaver_make_tables:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_board:nn
 {
  \newgame
  \fenboard{#2 ~ #1 ~ - ~ - ~ 0 ~ 1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_caption:n
 {
  \scalebox{\l__svend_opgaver_mag_tl}{\showboard}\par
  \vspace*{2ex}
  {\LARGE Løsning: ~ \textcolor{blue}{#1}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__svend_opgaver_make_tables:
 {
  \bool_if:NT \l__svend_opgaver_single_bool { \begin{figure}[!htbp] \centering }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { 1 } % start
   { \l__svend_opgaver_n_int } % step
   { \seq_count:N \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq } % end
   {
    \bool_if:NF \l__svend_opgaver_single_bool { \begin{figure}[!htbp] \centering }
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \l__svend_opgaver_n_int - 1 }
     {
      \tl_if_empty:xF
       { \seq_item:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq { ##1+####1 } }
       {
        \begin{minipage}[b]{ \dim_eval:n { \textwidth/\l__svend_opgaver_n_int } }
        \centering
        \seq_item:Nn \l__svend_opgaver_tables_out_seq { ##1+####1 }
        \end{minipage}
       }
     }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__svend_opgaver_single_bool { \\ \bigskip } { \end{figure} }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l__svend_opgaver_single_bool { \end{figure} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nF { x }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\opgaverLoesninger[mag=0.5,n=4,single]{
  w, 6k1/6p1/1p5p/3r4/1P6/6P1/4B1KP/8, Lc4 \\
  w, 1k6/pp6/2p3p1/4n1P1/8/P6P/KP1B4/8, Lf4 \\
  w, 8/1p4kp/p5p1/B7/3n4/1P5P/2P3P1/6K1, Lc3 \\
  w, k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8, Le4 \\
  w, k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8, Le4
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks really nice! Thank you very much, egreg!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Isn't the extended version even more interesting? `;-)`

Comment: With the magnifying/scaling options it's now very ineresting. `:-)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added a `single` option that makes a single `figure` environment. Just a few changes as you can see. `:-)`

Comment: Really cool. Any chance that you will implement Ulrike's suggestion in her [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399810/macro-with-more-than-9-arguments#comment995310_399817)?

Answer (score 10):

I think you are looking more or less for something like this (I disable the \hestA-command as the dimension `\svarstedA` is nowhere defined).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xskak}

\setchessboard{smallboard}

\newcommand*\hestA[2][\svarstedA]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi]{#2}}}

\newcommand*\opgaverLoesningerA[1]{{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand*\opgaverLoesningerEkstra[6]{%
  \def\tempA{#1}%
  \def\tempB{#2}%
  \def\tempC{#3}%
  \def\tempD{#4}%
  \def\tempE{#5}%
  \def\tempF{#6}%
  \opgaverLoesninger
}

\newcommand*\opgaverLoesninger[6]{%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newchessgame[setfen=\tempB\space \tempA - - 0 1,print]%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{\tempC}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newchessgame[setfen=\tempE \space \tempD - - 0 1,print]%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{\tempF}}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newchessgame[setfen = #2 #1 - - 0 1,print]%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{#3}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \newchessgame[setfen= #5 #4 - - 0 1,print]%
    \vspace*{2ex}

    {\LARGE Løsning: \opgaverLoesningerA{#6}}%
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\opgaverLoesningerEkstra%
  {w}{6k1/6p1/1p5p/3r4/1P6/6P1/4B1KP/8}{Lc4}%
  {w}{1k6/pp6/2p3p1/4n1P1/8/P6P/KP1B4/8}{Lf4}%
  {w}{8/1p4kp/p5p1/B7/3n4/1P5P/2P3P1/6K1}{Lc3}%
  {w}{k7/p6p/1p4p1/3r4/1P5P/P5P1/1KB5/8}{Le4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice! One small thing: How do I get rid of the small box next to the board, which indicates whether it's white or black to move? (I'll accept ypur answer as soon as this small annoyance is fixed.)

Comment: Add `showmover=false` to the \setchessboard:`\setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false}`. You can find the description of this keys in the `chessboard` documentation.

Comment: HI Ulrike. Sorry, but I've accepted Enrico's answer instead since it's more flexible. (Again: Thank you for helping me!)

Comment: That's okay -- I didn't try to improve your code, I mostly corrected the chess related commands. But @egreg doesn't use the best command to set the board. You should better use the xskak/chessboard commands from my answer (`\newchessgame[setfen = ...]`), `\fenboard` and `\showboard` are from the skak package and while they work they are a bit alien and not so flexible.

Comment: Hmmm! I've just noticed some "unexpected" behaviour: Assume I change the first of the 12 arguments of `\opgaverLoesningerEkstra` in your code from `w` to `b` then the square next to board still indicates that it's white's turn.

Comment: Also: I've posted a related question on [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402802/wrongly-defined-macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402802/wrongly-defined-macro). Can and will you help me fix the problem there?