# Wrongly defined macro

Tags: macros, xskak

Consider the following example where the code is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399817/15874 and modified a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{xskak}

\def\svarstedB{3.7em}
\newcommand*\hestB[2][\svarstedB]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi]{#2}}}
\newcommand*\matLoesninger[1]{\hestB{\textcolor{blue}{\smash{#1}}}}

\newcommand*\matTo[6]{%
  \def\tempA{#1}%
  \def\tempB{#2}%
  \def\tempC{#3}%
  \def\tempD{#4}%
  \def\tempE{#5}%
  \def\tempF{#6}%
  \matToEkstra}
\newcommand*\matToEkstra[5]{%
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
 \LARGE
 \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \ifblank{\tempA}{\vphantom{1}}{\textbf{\tempA}}%
    \vspace*{-2ex}

    \scalebox{1}{\newchessgame[setfen = \tempC\space \tempB - - 0 1, print]}%

    \hspace*{1.2em} Hvid \hspace*{2em} Sort
    \vspace*{-1ex}

    \begin{flushleft}
      \ifstrequal%
        {\tempB}{w}%
        {\hspace*{1.1em}%
         1.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempD}%
         \hspace*{0.8em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempE}%
         \vspace*{0.6ex}

         \hspace*{1.1em}%
         2.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempF}}%
        {\hspace*{1.1em}%
         1.%
         \hspace*{5.1em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempD}%
         \vspace*{0.6ex}

         \hspace*{1.1em}%
         2.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempE}%
         \hspace*{0.8em}%
         \matLoesninger{\tempF}}%
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
   \centering
    \ifblank{\tempA}{\vphantom{1}}{\textbf{\fpeval{\tempA+1}}}%
    \vspace*{-2ex}

    \scalebox{1}{\newchessgame[setfen = #2 #1 - - 0 1, print]}%

    \hspace*{1.2em} Hvid \hspace*{2em} Sort
    \vspace*{-1ex}

    \begin{flushleft}
      \ifstrequal%
        {#1}{w}%
        {\hspace*{1.1em}%
         1.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{#3}%
         \hspace*{0.8em}%
         \matLoesninger{#4}%
         \vspace*{0.6ex}

         \hspace*{1.1em}%
         2.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{#5}}%
        {\hspace*{1.1em}%
         1.%
         \hspace*{5.1em}%
         \matLoesninger{#3}%
         \vspace*{0.6ex}

         \hspace*{1.1em}%
         2.%
         \hspace*{0.6em}%
         \matLoesninger{#4}%
         \hspace*{0.8em}%
         \matLoesninger{#5}}%
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\matTo%
  {15}%
  {w}{5r1k/ppq4p/4p2p/2PnNp2/5P2/P6P/1B4P1/5R1K}{Sf7+}{Kg8}{Sxh6\#}%
  {b}{5rk1/1pp4p/p3R1p1/3R1n2/6B1/2P5/2PQ2PP/5K2}{Sg3+}{Ke1}{Tf1\#}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't matter if I set the value of the second argument of `\matTo` to `b` or `w`, the macro registres it as not being `w`. (The code works just fine for the chessboard printed inside the minipage to the right but not the one printed to the right.)

What is wrong with my macro and how do I fix it?

(It's probably really easy but I simply can't find the error. `:-(`)

I simply don't understand why the

```
\ifstrequal%
  {\tempB}{w}
```

part of my macro inside the first minipage is wrong.

P.S. Don't look at the page layout when the chessboards are printed; it's really ugly at the moment.

Comment: Side remark: In my opinion your code is unreadable and unmaintainable. Why do you insist to write commands with 11 arguments? Why all this temp-commands without meaning? And why do you mix layout and calculations in this way? Why do write commands which are nearly 100 lines long?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please feel free to shorten and/or simplify the code. `:-)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure ... I'm still doing something wrong. Any chance I can make you change my code in order for it to work as I would like it to? (I'm probably just confusing myself now and I get more and more frustrated ...)

Comment: I have no idea the code is as Ulrike indicated rather long and confusing and you give little indication what it is supposed to do, i just observed you are testing if #1 iw w but in your example #1 is 15 and #2 is w, so that looked wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The command has actually 11 argument as two commands are chained and #1 is #6 (or something like this).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah yes thanks, I was just eyeballing it, I didn't try to run it or guess what it was trying to do (but I'll delete the comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ulrike gave my the solution in her answer to one of my comments to her answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`xskak`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xskak):

> All chessboard keys are processed normally. You can even print
>   directly the board by using the key print. The **only exceptions** are
>   the keys maxfield and zero that change the size of the board – skak
>   doesn’t like unusual sizes of the board – and **the keys mover and
>   fullmove** which are overwritten by the (eventually default) value of
>   key moveid

This means that if you want to set the mover, you should either add the player explictly in `\newchessgame`, or use `\chessboard` to print the board:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{xskak}

\setchessboard{tinyboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame[setfen=5rk1/1pp4p/p3R1p1/3R1n2/6B1/2P5/2PQ2PP/5K2 b - - 0 1,print] % wrong

\newchessgame[setfen=5rk1/1pp4p/p3R1p1/3R1n2/6B1/2P5/2PQ2PP/5K2 b - - 0 1,player=b,print] % correct

\chessboard[setfen=5rk1/1pp4p/p3R1p1/3R1n2/6B1/2P5/2PQ2PP/5K2 b - - 0 1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

As answer to the comment:

You are using the wrong command for the test: `\ifstrequal` doesn't expand the strings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\def\tempB{w}

\ifstrequal{\tempB}{w}{true}{false}
\ifdefstring{\tempB}{w}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't explaining myself correctly (sorry!). The actual problem is with the position of the line segments underneath the diagrams. I want the position to change depending on whether I choose `w` or `b` as the second argument of my macro. This works for the diagram to the left (via the seventh argument of the macro) in my code but not for the diagram to the right and I don't know why.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: Finally, I got it! Thank you very much, Ulrike! ... If you can make my code more readable, I would be very interested in seeking what you can come up with. `:-)`

Comment: I'll accept your answer shortly ... also if you don't improve on my code, of course.

Comment: Sorry but as I already wrote: your code is basically unreadable. It would take an hour to find out what you are trying to achieve and why you use the various command (e.g. the figure, all the smash and more) and then one would have to rewrite the code from scratch. That's too much time for one answer.

Comment: By the way, would a bounty on, say, 100 reputation points make it worthwhile to spend some time to improve on my code? `:-)`