# How to put a continued function "\foocontinued" inside cvitem in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, arguments

I have a function in a moderncv format that I need more than 9 arguments for. If I use the "\foocontinued" [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments) I have the following problems.

1. If I place `\foocontinued` inside the item like `\cvitem{}{\foocontinued}` I get the following error: "Argument of \foocontinued has an extra }"
2. If I place `\foocontinued` outside the cvitem but inside the command foo the tenth argument appears on a line as shown by the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,url = false]{biblatex}
\firstname{Author}
\familyname{}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\newcommand\foo[9]{%
    \cvitem{[#1]}{
    #2
    #3
    #4
    #5
    #6
    #7
    #8
    #9 .The end of the normal function. Item 10 should follow this but instead in on a new line.    } \foocontinued   } 
\newcommand\foocontinued[1]{
    This is item #1  
}

% build the document 
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}

\end{document}
```

How can I get a 10th argument inside cvitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winging this, but it should work:

```
\newcommand\foo[9]{\foocontinued{#1}{#2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 #8 #9}}
\newcommand\foocontinued[3]{\cvitem{[#1]}{#2 This is item #3}}
```

Comment: Not sure why you need the #2, but this code works.