# Define macros avoiding duplicate code

Tags: macros

I'm using a macro for my figures

```
\newcommand{\figureone}[3]{%
\begin{figure*}%
\centering
\ifx&#3&\includegraphics{#1}\else\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#1}\fi
\caption{#2}
\label{fig:#1}
\end{figure*}
}
```

and the same macro with `center` in place of `figure*` because in some cases I don't want floats.

I'd like to avoid duplicating code, because in my real world I have several of such macros for figures.

So, is there a way to define two macros using `figure*` or `center` starting from a *prototype* macro?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Fixed, thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 5):

You can make macros to make macros. I'm going to modify your template macro to have the third argument be an optional argument, so you'd call,

```
\figureone{file.png}{This is the caption}[0.3]
```

or

```
\figureone{file.png}{This is the caption}
```

So let's call our macro-defining macro `\newfigure` and it will take two arguments: the name of the macro to define and the name of the environment (as an aside, I’m assuming `xparse` here. If your LaTeX is current, it will be in the kernel, but if not you'll need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` to load it).

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfigure}{ m m }{%
```

`\newfigure`, in turn will do its own `\NewDocumentCommand` to define your new figure command:

```
   \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{ m m o }{%
      \begin{#2}%
        \centering
```

Hmm, how do we let LaTeX know in this definition within a definition that we want the arguments to what we're defining and not the arguments that we've passed to `\newfigure`? In this instance, we double the `#` to let LaTeX know that these belong to the inner definition.¹<sup>,</sup>² so we can rewrite your `\ifx`…`\fi` as:

```
        \IfNoValueTF {##3}
          {\includegraphics{##1}}
          {\includegraphics[width=##3\textwidth]{#1}}
```

and your caption and label as

```
        \caption{##2}
        \label{fig:##1}
```

And then finish off the definition:

```
      \end{#2}
    }
```

---

1. If you had a macro definition inside a macro definition inside a macro definition, you would double again—`####1`. I'm not sure how deeply the madness can be nested—I've never probed, but looking through the contents of `tex-live/**` I see as deep as 5 levels (32 `#`s!). My personal favorite string from this search was `\def####1########1##1########2` Which defines a two-argument command using a third-level macro's first argument for the name and a second-level macro's first argument as the delimiter between the two arguments.
2. This also would apply to the `#` for templates of an inner primitive `\halign` or `\valign`. If you aren't familiar with those commands, just ignore this footnote.

Answer (score 2):

In case the name of the environment and the way captions are to be generated are the only things to change from macro to macro, with a prototype-macro just shift arguments up by two and as the prototype-macro's first argument use the name of the environment and as the prototype-macro's second argument use the desired `\caption`/`\captionof`/`\@gobble`-command.

Then define the other macros to call the prototype-macro with the first argument (environment-name) and the second argument (`\caption`/`\captionof`/`\@gobble`-command) provided so that the prototype-macro's subsequent three arguments will not come from the other macros' definitions but will be gathered at the time of carrying out the other macros.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newcommand{\PrototypeThing}[5]{%
  \begin{#1}%
  \centering
  \ifx&#5&\includegraphics{#3}\else\includegraphics[{width=#5\textwidth}]{#3}\fi
  #2{#4}%
  \label{fig:#3}%
  \end{#1}%
}%

\newcommand*{\figureone}{\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}}
\newcommand*{\centerone}{\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\figureone{example-image-a.jpg}{caption}{1}

\centerone{example-image-b.jpg}{caption}{.3}

\end{document}
```

`\figureone` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}`.

Thus

`\figureone{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}`.

`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}` in turn yields:

```latex
\begin{figure*}%
\centering
\ifx&⟨width⟩&\includegraphics{⟨fileNlabel⟩}\else\includegraphics[{width=⟨width⟩\textwidth}]{⟨fileNlabel⟩}\fi
\caption{⟨caption⟩}%
\label{fig:⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\end{figure*}%
```

---

`\centerone` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}`.

Thus

`\centerone{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}`.

`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}{⟨width⟩}` in turn yields:

```latex
\begin{center}%
\centering
\ifx&⟨width⟩&\includegraphics{⟨fileNlabel⟩}\else\includegraphics[{width=#5\textwidth}]{⟨fileNlabel⟩}\fi
\captionof{figure}{⟨caption⟩}%
\label{fig:⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\end{center}%
```

---

---

Using xparse you can make the *⟨width⟩*-argument optional:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrototypeThing}{mmmmo}{%
  \begin{#1}%
  \centering
  \IfNoValueTF{#5}{\includegraphics}{\includegraphics[{width=#5\textwidth}]}{#3}%
  #2{#4}%
  \label{fig:#3}%
  \end{#1}%
}%

\newcommand*{\figureone}{\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}}
\newcommand*{\centerone}{\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\noindent\figureone{example-image-a.jpg}{figureonecaption}[1]

\noindent\centerone{example-image-b.jpg}{centeronecaption}[.3]

\end{document}
```

`\figureone` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}`.

Thus

`\figureone{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]`.

`\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]` in turn yields:

```latex
\begin{figure*}%
\centering
\IfNoValueTF{⟨width⟩}{\includegraphics}{\includegraphics[{width=⟨width⟩\textwidth}]}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\caption{⟨caption⟩}%
\label{fig:⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\end{figure*}%
```

---

`\centerone` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}`.

Thus

`\centerone{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]` yields:
`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]`.

`\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}{⟨caption⟩}[⟨width⟩]` in turn yields:

```latex
\begin{center}%
\centering
\IfNoValueTF{⟨width⟩}{\includegraphics}{\includegraphics[{width=⟨width⟩\textwidth}]}{⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\captionof{figure}{⟨caption⟩}%
\label{fig:⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
\end{center}%
```

Comment: This technique is very interesting, the problem is that some of my real world macros need 4-5 parameters for the prototype and 8 or more parameters for the final macro, so I need more than 9 parameters overall, how would you solve it?

Comment: @mmj  key=value-interface. Prototype-macro takes some default key=value-pairs, trailed by a comma, trailed by an argument for the comma-list with the user-provided key=value-pairs. Package pgfkeys might be of interest. The discussion [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/118714) might be of interest, too.

Comment: I think I will finally refactor my macros with a key=value interface using pgfkeys. The hurry for a solution prevented me to use it from the beginning.

Comment: @mmj If you are willing to take up with LaTeX3 (which at CTAN for whatsoever obscure reasons is still called "experimental"), which can seamlessly be integrated into LaTeX2ε-documents via `\usepackage{xparse}`/`\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff`, then the l3keys-package might be of interest. On CTAN LaTeX3 can be found at: [https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel).

Comment: @mmj An overview over language- and naming-conventions can be found at: [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf).
The LaTeX3 Interfaces and the single packages forming the LaTeX3-kernel are documented at: [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Comment: @mmj Coding-conventions and style guide can be found at: [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf).
The commented LaTeX3 Sources can be found at: [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you gain very much using this inflexible approach. For instance, what about the optional argument to `\caption`? What about other options to `\includegraphics` (think to trimming, for instance)?

We can avoid most code duplication as follows, also supporting the options I mentioned. But I don't believe this is really useful.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\figureone}{sO{}mO{#5}mo}{%
  % start: if *-version, center
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{center}}{\begin{figure*}\centering}%
  \IfValueTF{#6}{%
    % a fraction is specified
    \includegraphics[width=#6\textwidth,#2]{#3}%
  }{%
    \includegraphics[#2]{#3}%
  }%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\captionof{figure}}{\caption}[#4]{#5}%
  \label{#3}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\end{center}}{\end{figure*}}%
}
```

Complete example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,capt-of}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\figureone}{sO{}mO{#5}mo}{%
  % start: if *-version, center
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{center}}{\begin{figure*}\centering}%
  \IfValueTF{#6}{%
    % a fraction is specified
    \includegraphics[width=#6\textwidth,#2]{#3}%
  }{%
    \includegraphics[#2]{#3}%
  }%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\captionof{figure}}{\caption}[#4]{#5}%
  \label{#3}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\end{center}}{\end{figure*}}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone*{example-image}{Figure in the column}[0.4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone*{example-image-a}[Short caption]{Long caption}[0.4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone*[trim=20 20 20 20,clip]{example-image-b}{Trimmed}[0.4]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone{example-image-c}{Figure in the column}

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone{example-image-16x9}[Short caption]{Long caption}[0.8]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\figureone[trim=20 20 20 20,clip]{example-image-1x1}{Trimmed}[0.8]

\lipsum[1][1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why you say this is not really useful? What would be your general approach? Consider I've many macros building figures either with 2, 3 or 4 images, side by side, one over the other or mixed, with single or multiple captions, with or without subcaptions, automatically resizing multiple images by height or by area.

Comment: @mmj My approach would be to use the proper environments.

Answer (score 1):

**In your comment to my first answer you added an aspect which should have been mentioned in the initial question already: Breaking the nine-argument-limit:**

> [...] the problem is that some of my real world macros need 4-5 parameters for the prototype and 8 or more parameters for the final macro, so I need more than 9 parameters overall, [...]

*I am not fond of macros taking many arguments: The more arguments, the more opportunities to erroneously put arguments in wrong order. This is not user-friendly.*

*Therefore I take this for an "academical" thing only—a request to see how such a thing can be done, just for the knowledge and the challenge, although one would not implement such a thing for daily usage.*

**As long as all "parameters" are mandatory undelimited arguments** I propose two "building bricks":

**Building brick 1:**

Have a `\romannumeral`-expansion-driven "macro-mechanism"

```latex
\CollectLArgs{⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity of value L⟩}{⟨Argument 1⟩}{⟨Argument 2⟩}...{⟨Argument L⟩}
```

which yields:

```latex
{{⟨Argument 1⟩}{⟨Argument 2⟩}...{⟨Argument L⟩}}
```

, i.e., which wraps a sequence of L undelimited arguments into a single argument which then contains/consists of a list of L undelimited arguments.

(With macro-mechanisms that are driven by `\romannumeral`-expansion you need exactly two expansion-steps/two "hits" by `\expandafter` for obtaining the result.)

**Building brick 2:**

Have a `\romannumeral`-expansion-driven "macro-mechanism"

```latex
\ExtractKthArg{⟨TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity of value K⟩}%
              {⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a Kth argument⟩}%
              {⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩}%
```

which works as follows:

In case there is no K<sup>th</sup> argument in the *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩*:
Does deliver *⟨tokens in case list of undelimited arguments doesn't have a K<sup>th</sup> argument⟩*.

In case there is a K<sup>th</sup> argument in the *⟨list of undelimited arguments⟩*:
Does deliver that K<sup>th</sup> argument with one level of braces removed.

(With macro-mechanisms that are driven by `\romannumeral`-expansion you need exactly two expansion-steps/two "hits" by `\expandafter` for obtaining the result.)

**You can use the two "building bricks"** for defining a generic macro-mechanism which processes an amount of L arguments, whereby L>9 is possible, the first ones of these L arguments being those whose defaults are to be changed for the non-generic macros/user-level-macros:

The generic macro-mechanism consists of a generic toplevel-macro which via `\expandafter`-trickery calls `\CollectLArgs` to deliver to a generic internal-macro, which processes exactly one argument, the L arguments turned into a single undelimited argument containing a list of L undelimited arguments.

This way the generic internal-macro's argument is a list of L undelimited arguments from which you can have extracted whichever you like/need by means of `\ExtractKthArg`.

---

In the example below `\ExtractKthArg` requires two expansion-steps/two "hits" by `\expandafter` to deliver the result.

Assume you want the 11<sup>th</sup> argument/element to be in typewriter-font.

You can do

```
\texttt{%
  \ExtractKthArg{11}%
                {}%
                {{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}}%
}%
```

This way  `\texttt` will start working and hereby also evaluate `\ExtractKthArg...`, which in turn delivers `11`.

Alternatively you can do:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\texttt
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExtractKthArg{11}%
                {}%
                {{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}}%
}%
```

This way the `\expandafter`-chain triggers carrying out `\ExtractKthArg` *before* `\texttt` comes to start working and you get:

```
\texttt{11}%
```

With these two snippets the differences in the order in time of expansion/carrying things out doesn't matter—the result in the end is the same.
But often the order in time in which expansion takes place and tokens are obtained does matter.

---

Let's create an example where the two mentioned "building-bricks" are implemented and used for defining both a `\PrototypeThing` which processes 17 arguments, the first two arguments being defaults that are to be provided within the definition-text of the user-level-macros, the following 15 to be provided by the user when calling the user-level-macros—so that the user-level-macros take 15 arguments:

Syntax is:

```latex
\PrototypeThing{⟨environment-name⟩}%
               {⟨caption-command⟩}%
               {⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
               {⟨caption-text⟩}%
               {⟨width⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 1⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 2⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 3⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 4⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 5⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 6⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 7⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 8⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 9⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 10⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 11⟩}%
               {⟨Dummy-Argument 12⟩}%
```

Based on `\PrototypeThing` you can easily define user-macros of definition-pattern

```latex
\newcommand⟨Cs-token⟩{%
  \PrototypeThing{⟨environment-name⟩}%
                 {⟨caption-command⟩}%
}%
```

with syntax

```
⟨Cs-token⟩{⟨fileNlabel⟩}%
          {⟨caption-text⟩}%
          {⟨width⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 1⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 2⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 3⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 4⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 5⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 6⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 7⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 8⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 9⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 10⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 11⟩}%
          {⟨Dummy-Argument 12⟩}%
```

Here we go:

```latex
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%%\UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%%\UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% BUILDING-BRICK 1: \CollectLArgs
%%=============================================================================
%%  \CollectLArgs{<TeX-<number>-quantity of value L>}%
%%               {<Argument 1>}{<Argument 2>}...{<Argument L>}%
%%
%% yields:
%%
%% {{<Argument 1>}{<Argument 2>}...{<Argument L>}}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps / by "hitting" \CollectLArgs with \expandafter twice.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\CollectLArgs[1]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\UD@CollectLArgs\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CollectLArgs[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral{#2}}{\UD@@CollectLArgs{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CollectLArgs[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CollectLArgs\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2{#3}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% BUILDING-BRICK 2: \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% \ExtractKthArg{<TeX-<number>-quantity of value K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of undelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of undelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps / by "hitting" \ExtractKthArg with \expandafter twice.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\PrototypeThing}{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\InternalPrototypeThing\CollectLArgs{17}%
}%
\newcommand{\InternalPrototypeThing}[1]{%
  \begin{\ExtractKthArg{1}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill
  \par\noindent User macro's 1st argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{3}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 2nd argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{4}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 3rd argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{5}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 4th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{6}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 5th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{7}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 6th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{8}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 7th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{9}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 8th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{10}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 9th argument: \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{11}{}{#1}}% 
  \par\noindent User macro's 10th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{12}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 11th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{13}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 12th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{14}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 13th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{15}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 14th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{16}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent User macro's 15th argument:  \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{17}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill
  \bigskip
  \par
  \centering
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\ExtractKthArg{5}{}{#1}}{%
    \includegraphics
  }{%
    \includegraphics[{width=\ExtractKthArg{5}{}{#1}\textwidth}]%
  }{\ExtractKthArg{3}{}{#1}}%
  \ExtractKthArg{2}{}{#1}{\ExtractKthArg{4}{}{#1}}%
  \label{fig:\ExtractKthArg{3}{}{#1}}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill
  \end{\ExtractKthArg{1}{}{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\figureone}{\PrototypeThing{figure*}{\caption}}
\newcommand*{\centerone}{\PrototypeThing{center}{\captionof{figure}}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures 

\newpage

\null

\figureone{example-image-a.jpg}{caption}{.3}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}

\newpage

\centerone{example-image-b.jpg}{caption}{1}{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}

\end{document}
```

[image]