# Not able to define a command with tikz-cd environment (Functor notation)

Tags: macros, tikz-cd

I've extended myself too much, so the short question is:

> Why can't  I define macros with the `tikzcd`package as defined below? (right above the "Old Solution" section)

---

### Description

I recently developed a notation for functors and it was tempting to use the `tikzcd` environment. However, the problem is that 1) The macro must have more than 9 entries (I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509766/238551)). 2) The spacing was pretty terrible.

I finded a solution using array and some rotations (the solution code will be at the end), but mostly it works fine.

[image: Old solution output]

But, when using big categories names or whatever, space between terms becomes way to strange and preety lame. Back to `tikzcd`, I've almost with some additional tricks (but mostly "fairier"):

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={0.22em}, column sep={0.01em}]
    {F}: & {\boldsymbol{\mathscr C}} \arrow[rr] &\hspace{0.5cm}& {\boldsymbol{\mathscr D}}        &   \\
    & {X} \arrow[dd,"{\phi}"'] \arrow[rr, mapsto] & & {F(X)} \arrow[dd,"{F(\phi)}"'] & {x} \arrow[dd,mapsto]\\
    & \,                                         & &              &   \\ 
    & {Y} \arrow[rr,mapsto]                     & & {Y}         & {F(\phi)(x)}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now the arrows adjust itself to each case. So im done and wanted to define that macro. Copying what I did in the old way, it should be:

```
%----------------
% Black Tex Magic
%----------------
% Provide a way to declare and renew a command in one command
\newcommand{\neworrenewcommand}[1]{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}

% Covariant functor
\newcommand{\covfunctor}[9]{
    \neworrenewcommand{\ccovfunctor}[2]{
        \begin{tikzcd}[row sep={0.22em}, column sep={0.01em}]
            {#1}: & {#2} \arrow[rr]                            &\hspace{0.5cm} & {#3}        &   \\
            & {#4} \arrow[dd,"{#8}"'] \arrow[rr, mapsto] & & {#5} \arrow[dd,"{#9}"'] & {##1} \arrow[dd,mapsto]\\
            & \,                                         & &              &   \\ 
            & {#6} \arrow[rr,mapsto]                     & & {#7}         & {##2}
        \end{tikzcd}
    }
    \ccovfunctor
}
```

Well... nothing could be that simple in TeX: It compiles an error but it doesn't show me exactly what it is. So... what went wrong?

### Old Solution

It uses the same `\neworrenewcommand` as above.

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\covfunctor}[9]{
    \neworrenewcommand{\ccovfunctor}[2]{
        \begin{array}{rcccc}
            {#1}: & \hphantom{{#8}} {#2} & \longrightarrow & {#3} &  \\
            &   \hphantom{{#8}} {#4}    &   \longmapsto   & {#5} & {##1}\\
            &  \begin{turn}{90}
                \ensuremath{\overset{\begin{turn}{270}
                            \scaleobj{0.7}{\ensuremath{{#8}}}
                    \end{turn}}{\longleftarrow}}
            \end{turn} &  & \begin{turn}{90}
                \ensuremath{\overset{\begin{turn}{270}
                            \scaleobj{0.7}{\ensuremath{{#9}}}
                    \end{turn}}{\longleftarrow}}
            \end{turn} \hphantom{\scaleobj{0.7}{{#9}}} & \begin{turn}{90}
                \reflectbox{\ensuremath{\longmapsto}}
            \end{turn}\\
            &  \hphantom{{#8}} {#6} & \longmapsto & {#7} & {##2}
        \end{array}
    }
    \ccovfunctor
}
```

Comment: A general remark: When you want a macro with more than 9 arguments, it’s usually better to use some kind of keyval syntax.

Comment: I agree with Gaussler.  Although in this case, are you really using this as a function?  Are you going to be having two or more of these, but with different entries?  If not, it would just be easier to type the diagram instead of having a macro type the diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe everything is in the link you posted and in your code. Note that `&\hspace{0.5cm}&` is not right, you should write `&[1cm]&` and it is not necessary an extra row, this space can be adjusted with `\\[5mm]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%This is a first attemp with only 7 arguments
\newcommand{\funtordia}[7]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep={0.22em}, column sep={0.01em}, ampersand replacement=\&]
    #1: \& \mathscr{#2} \arrow[rr] \&[1cm]\& \mathscr{#3} \&   \\
    \& #5 \arrow[d,"#4"'] \arrow[rr, mapsto] \& \& #1(#5) \arrow[d,"#1(#4)"'] \& #7 \arrow[d,mapsto]\\[5mm]
    \& #6 \arrow[rr,mapsto]                     \& \& #1(#6)         \& #7\cdot #4
  \end{tikzcd}
}

%This is taken from the egreg's answer in the link you posted
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewWeirdCommand}{mm}
 {% #1 = command to define, #2 = replacement text
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__covfun_args_tl { ##1 }
    #2
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Arg}{m}
 {
  \tl_item:Nn \l__covfun_args_tl { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__covfun_parse_args_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewWeirdCommand{\covfunctor}{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep={0.22em}, column sep={0.01em}, ampersand replacement=\&]
    \Arg{1}: \& \mathscr{\Arg{2}} \arrow[rr] \&[1cm]\& \mathscr{\Arg{3}} \&   \\
    \& \Arg{5} \arrow[d,"\Arg{4}"'] \arrow[rr, mapsto] \& \& \Arg{8} \arrow[d,"\Arg{7}"'] \& \Arg{10} \arrow[d,mapsto]\\[5mm]
    \& \Arg{6} \arrow[rr,mapsto]                     \& \& \Arg{9}         \& \Arg{11}
  \end{tikzcd}
}

\begin{document}

\funtordia{G}{D}{C}{d}{D}{D'}{y}%
\qquad%
\covfunctor{{F}{A}{B}{a}{A}{A'}{b}{B}{B'}{x}{y}}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following
[image]

Comment: You have done a great job.

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly. Just a litle twiks and i also did it the contra-variant case.

Answer (score 5):

Using eleven arguments is very error prone. I suggest a different approach with a more natural syntax “by column”. The idea is to store the column data and to pick the needed items when they're needed in the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the syntax will be by columns:
% \describefunctor{F}{\mathcal{C},X,\phi,Y}{\mathcal{D},F(X),F(\phi),F(Y)}[x,F(\phi)(x)]
% with the last column optional

\NewDocumentCommand{\describefunctor}{mmmo}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__mezzovilla_three_bool
    \mezzovilla_functor:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { }
   }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__mezzovilla_three_bool
    \mezzovilla_functor:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\clist_new:N \l__mezzovilla_functor_one_clist
\clist_new:N \l__mezzovilla_functor_two_clist
\clist_new:N \l__mezzovilla_functor_three_clist
\bool_new:N \l__mezzovilla_three_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mezzovilla_functor:nnnn
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l__mezzovilla_functor_one_clist { #2 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__mezzovilla_functor_two_clist { #3 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__mezzovilla_functor_three_clist { #4 }
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand~replacement=\&]
  #1\colon \&[-3em]
  \__mezzovilla_item:nn { one } { 1 } \arrow[r] \&
  \__mezzovilla_item:nn { two } { 1 }
  \bool_if:NT \l__mezzovilla_three_bool { \&[-1.5em] }
  \\[-1.5em]
  \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { one } { 2 }
     \arrow[r,mapsto]
     \arrow[d,swap,"\__mezzovilla_item:nn { one } { 3 }"]
  \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { two } { 2 }
     \arrow[d,swap,"\__mezzovilla_item:nn { two } { 3 }"]
  \bool_if:NT \l__mezzovilla_three_bool
   { \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { three } { 1 } \arrow[d,mapsto] }
  \\
  \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { one } { 3 }
     \arrow[r,mapsto]
  \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { two } { 3 }
  \bool_if:NT \l__mezzovilla_three_bool
   { \& \__mezzovilla_item:nn { three } { 2 } }
  \end{tikzcd}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__mezzovilla_item:nn
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l__mezzovilla_functor_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\describefunctor{F}{\mathcal{C},X,\phi,Y}{\mathcal{D},F(X),F(\phi),F(Y)}[x,F(\phi)(x)]
\]

\[
\describefunctor{F}{\mathcal{C},X,\phi,Y}{\mathcal{D},F(X),F(\phi),F(Y)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because there’s always something to learn in your answers (even when mine is a copy-paste of your code in other post)

Comment: I really liked this approach, making it possible to omit the map of each funtor. Unfortunately, there was some error when I didn't include a name for the funtor image. I tried with `..., { }, ...` and other "gambiarras" (no nice translation, kind of a trick) but it was unable to compile. I saved the alternative in the same way, thank you very much.