# TikZ - Node with multiple text fields

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make a repeatable node (node is probably not the right word here) that looks like this:

[image: complex node]

The `Field` values are individual input texts.

I've thought about using `\newcommand` to make the outer node and then fill the inside of the outer node with other nodes and text, but I run out of arguments; `\newcommand` takes up to 9 inputs and this would require 10 inputs plus the positioning and labeling of the outer node.

There is the TeX hack that "allows" more than 9 inputs: [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments#2134)

Is there a better way to do this?

#### First attempt

This is starting to look like something.

[image: first attempt]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\iitem[3]{%say
    \node [#1,minimum size=3cm] (#2) {};
    \node [anchor=north west] (title) at (#2.north west) {\footnotesize Title};
    \node [anchor=north west] (title field) at (title.south east) {\footnotesize #3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\iitem{draw}{test}{demo title};
%\node[left=of test,draw] (test 2) {test 2 node};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you didn't use `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` , `left= of` was not recognized.

Comment: Whoops.. that's right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\newcommand` with just a single argument, but that argument consists of all 10 fields separated by `/`s (forward slashes). Then `\foreach` (which doesn't actually loop since there's only one argument) can be used to read each of the fields into a different variable.

If any of your "fields" contains a forward slash it must be enclosed in braces, e.g., `{Field/1}/{Field/2}/...`

Then the rest of the macro draws the image with lines and rectangles, placing the text as `node` contents. You can change the values of `\fieldheight` and `\fieldwidth` to adjust the size of the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fieldheight}{.5cm}
\newcommand{\fieldwidth}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\makecard}[1]{\tikz[font=\sffamily, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0ex]{
    \foreach \ffa/\ffb/\ffc/\ffd/\ffe/\fff/\ffg/\ffh/\ffi/\ffj in {#1}{
    \draw[thick] (0,0) node[below right]{Title} rectangle (4*\fieldwidth,-9*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-2*\fieldheight)rectangle node[above]{\ffa}(4*\fieldwidth,-2*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-3*\fieldheight)node[above right]{Dwg No.}-- node[above, pos=.65]{\ffb}(4*\fieldwidth,-3*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-4*\fieldheight)node[above right]{SCH No.}-- node[above, pos=.65]{\ffc}(4*\fieldwidth,-4*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-5*\fieldheight)node[above right]{Ref Des}-- node[above, pos=.75]{Qty}(4*\fieldwidth,-5*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-6*\fieldheight)node[above right]{\ffd}-- node[above, pos=.75]{\ffe}(4*\fieldwidth,-6*\fieldheight);
    \draw (0,-8*\fieldheight)node[above right]{\fff} rectangle (\fieldwidth,-7*\fieldheight);
    \draw (\fieldwidth,-8*\fieldheight)node[above right]{\ffg} rectangle (2*\fieldwidth,-7*\fieldheight);
    \draw (2*\fieldwidth,-8*\fieldheight)node[above right]{\ffh} rectangle (3*\fieldwidth,-7*\fieldheight);
    \draw (3*\fieldwidth,-8*\fieldheight)node[above right]{\ffi} rectangle (4*\fieldwidth,-7*\fieldheight);
    \path (0,-9*\fieldheight)rectangle node[above]{\ffj}(4*\fieldwidth,-9*\fieldheight);
}}}

\begin{document}

\makecard{Field 1/Field 2/Field 3/Field 4/Field 5/Field 6/Field 7/Field 8/Field 9/Field 10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TikZ` is not required here. Your "node" is a simple `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\fieldWidth{1.3cm}
\newcommand\makecard[1]{%
    \foreach \ffa/\ffb/\ffc/\ffd/\ffe/\fff/\ffg/\ffh/\ffi/\ffj in {#1} {%
        \sffamily%
        \begin{tabular}{|p{\fieldWidth}p{\fieldWidth}p{\fieldWidth}p{\fieldWidth}|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Title}\\
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ffa} & \\
            \hline
            Dwg No. && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ffb} & \\
            \hline
            SCH No. && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ffc} & \\
            \hline
            Ref Des && \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Qty}\\
            \hline
            \ffd && \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\ffe}\\
            \hline
            &&&\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\fff} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ffg} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ffh} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ffi}\\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\ffj}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \makecard{Field 1/Field 2/Field 3/Field 4/Field 5/Field 6/Field 7/Field 8/Field 9/Field 10}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]